# ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework. How to avoid duplicate rows?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

So I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to implement an address manager.I'm using Linq2Entity Framework. I've got a table with contacts and one with phone numbers. These two tables are linked by a contact_has_phone_number table. The Entity Framework enables me to get all phone numbers that are assigned to one contact. This is done by calling contact.PhoneNumbers which returns a collection of phone numbers. A new number is added with contact.PhoneNumber.Add(number). The Problem is that I am getting duplicate phone number entries in the phone number table. What I would like to get is that an existing phone number only gets linked in the contact_has_phone_number table. 
For Example:

Table "contact"

```
ID_Contact  | First_Name |  Last_Name  
1           |   Jeff     |    Bridges  
2           |   Peter    |    Miller
```

Table "contact_has_phone_number"

```
ID_Contact  | ID_Number  
1           |    1  
1           |    2  
2           |    1
```

Table "phone_number"

```
ID_Number  | Number  
1          | 1234567  
2          | 7654321
```

At the momonet I would get 3 rows in the "phone_number" table with 2 rows with identical numbers.

```
ID_Number  | Number  
1          | 1234567  
2          | 7654321  
3          | 1234567
```

Would be a blast if you could help me with this.

Comment: Show the code used to get current code numbers and store new number.

Answer (score 0):

This is a many to many situation.  I have encountered a situation like this (not contact related) and this is what I did.

In creating a new contact, I will have the contact details as well as the phone numbers. the below code can be used

```
public void AddNewContact(Contact contact)
{
    var storedPhones = context.PhoneNumbers.Select(s => s).ToList();
            foreach (var s in contact.PhoneList)
            {
                var p = s.PhoneNumber; 
                var storedPhone = storedPhone s.Where(f => f.PhoneNumber == p).Select(t => t).FirstOrDefault();
                if (storedPhone == null)
                {
                    var newPhoneNumber = MySqlEFModel.PhoneNumber.CreatePhoneNumber(Guid.NewGuid(), p);
                    context.AddToPhoneNumbers(newPhone);
                    contact.PhoneNumbers.Add(newPhone);
                }
                else
                {
                    contact.PhoneNumbers.Add(storedPhone);
                }
            }
        context.AddToContacts(contact);
        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

EDIT:

I should have done this at the beginning of the method, before the loop.

```
                    var newContact = MySqlEFModel.Contact.CreateContact(keyfields, ... ... , ...);
```

Then, the lines

contact.PhoneNumbers.Add(storedPhone);

will become

newContact.PhoneNumbers.Add(storedPhone);

Comment: So if you add a new Number that already exists you just add a reference of the existing number to the the contact?

Comment: I thought about that and will try it right now. Thanks so far

Comment: You must be careful when using this method, since if the phone number is changed, it will change it for all contacts using the number.. which may not be what you want.  You will have to add extra logic to your update method that creates a new number if it is shared by other contacts.

Comment: Good observation Mystere Man.  In my situation, I didn't have to worry about that because the 'PhoneNumber' equivalent entity does not have the requirement of being edited.

Comment: @Gboyega Sulaiman: To create a new Phone Number I need to create a primary key as you can see in the "phone_number". How can I do that?

Comment: @benn - You could use the phone number itself as a primary key, since it's just a number, and will be unique to that phone number itself.  However, to keep it simple you will probably just want to make sure your phone number table's phone number id is set to be an identity column, then the id is created for you when you save changes.  You just don't fill in that field when creating a new item.

Comment: @Gboyega Sulaiman: Thank you very much. I managed it to work partly. The new contact is added and the id's of the existing phone numbers get set properly. The Problem is that each number is getting inserted twice. Once with reference to the existing number and once with a totally new number. I think the Problem is that the contact which is received by the AddNewContact Method already has these numbers in it's collection. I think I have to remove these before setting the reference to the existing number. Is that right?

Comment: @Gboyega Sulaiman: Sorry for all the questions bt I'm trying to solve this for a long time and I'm so glad that finally someone is able to help me. There is still something I don't understand in your code. The foreach loop should loop threw the phone numbers of the given contact right. You mixed up the the method call right? If so the problem is that adding a number to the collection is changing itself an lopping will end.

Comment: @benn: Yes I think I mixed it up.the 'contact' class in my situation is just the model, not entity. So, this code line contact.PhoneNumbers.Add(newPhone) is wrong should be the contact entity created from the context and then its property populated from the passed in contact model. I will edit the answer to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with duplicate records occurring using EF. After much mess, I finally discovered the solution:

You must always attach newly created entities to a table before executing .SaveChanges()

My issue was that SaveChanges was being called before attaching a new entity I created to a table so there was one entity created after SaveChanges was called and another duplicate entity called after AddObject();SaveChanges(); was run.

TL;DR:

Result with duplicate records:

```
Pro.Machine = new XXXDB.Machine();
Pro.Machine.Translate(machine); // SaveChanges() was being called by this method.
XXXDB.XXXDB.DB.Machines.AddObject(Pro.Machine);
XXXDB.XXXDB.DB.SaveChanges();
```

was changed to:

```
Pro.Machine = new XXXDB.Machine();
XXXDB.XXXDB.DB.Machines.AddObject(Pro.Machine);
Pro.Machine.Translate(machine); //SaveChanges() occurs after attaching to the machines table.
XXXDB.XXXDB.DB.SaveChanges();
```

Note: database names changed to protect privileged client.